# Exception handling with http gateways in spring integration

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, exception, spring-integration

I have a module in our project that exposes restful webservices using spring integration http inbound gatweways . I would like to add some error handling to it to be able translate underlying exceptions into error json responses with appropriate result codes. In my other spring mvc modules ,i have acheived the same with using @controlleradvice and @exceptionhandler. is there a way to have similar behavior implemented on spring integration http gateways . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an `error-channel` to the gateway and handle the exception/return some result on the error flow. The `ErrorMessage` payload is a `MessagingException` which has two properties: `failedMessage` and `cause`.